# Django; Problem with Displaying Items Appropriately

Tags: django

I am learning Django by building an application, called TravelBuddies. It will allow travelers to plan their trip and keep associated travel items (such as bookings, tickets, copy of passport, insurance information, etc), as well as create alerts for daily activities. The application will also able to update local information such as weather or daily news to the traveler. Travelers can also share the travel information with someone or have someone to collaborate with them to plan for the trip.

I am facing a problem. I have added two activities for Kuala Lumpur through Django admin. They are "Going to Botanical Garden" and "Going to Aquaria."

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/triplist/, I see this page:
[image]

When I click on **Kuala Lumpur**, I see this page at http://127.0.0.1:8000/triplist/kuala-lumpur/:
[image]

The two activities, called "Going to Botanical Garden" and "Going to Aquaria," cannot be separated. They are supposed to be displayed in this way:

```
Activity name: Going to Botanical Garden
Date: Dec. 4, 2019
Time: 12:34 p.m.
Location: KL Sentral
Item Type: Ticket
Item Number: E12342


Activity name: Going to Aquaria
Date: Dec. 4, 2019
Time: 1:58 p.m.
Location: Bukit Bintang
Item Type: Ticket
Item Number: C45776
```

That means, there must be a gap between the two activities. But I am unable to do it.

Here are my codes in `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


# class Coplanner(models.Model):
#     coplanner_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
#
#     def __str__(self):
#         return self.coplanner_name

class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    planner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    add_coplanner = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trip_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.trip_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Activity(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now= True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.activity_name

    def save(self):
        super(Activity, self).save()
        self.slug = '%i-%s' % (
            self.id, slugify(self.trip.trip_name)
        )
        super(Activity, self).save()
```

Here are my codes in `views.py`:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Trip, Activity


class TripListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'trips/triplist.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_trips'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Trip.objects.all()


class ActivityView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Trip
    template_name = 'trips/activity.html'
```

Here are my codes in urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'trips'

urlpatterns = [
    path('triplist/', views.TripListView.as_view(), name='triplist'),
    path('triplist/<slug:slug>/', views.ActivityView.as_view(), name='activity'),
]
```

Here are my codes in `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class TripsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'trips'
```

Here are my codes in `triplist.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'trips/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% block title%}Trip list{% endblock %}
    <title>Trip list</title>
</head>


<body>
    {% block content %}
    <!--Page content-->
    <h1>This is Trip List Page</h1>


    <ul>
        {% for trip in all_trips %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'trips:activity' trip.slug %}">{{ trip.trip_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}


    </ul>

    <img src="{% static "images/botanical-garden.jpg" %}" alt="Botanical Garden" />
    <!-- New line -->
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

</html>
```

Here are my codes in `activity.html`:

```
{% extends 'trips/base.html' %}
{% block title%}
Detail
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<h3>These are the details for {{trip.trip_name}} </h3>

<ul>{% for trip_item in trip.activity_set.all %}
    <li>Activity name: {{ trip_item.activity_name }}</li>
    <li>Date: {{ trip_item.date }}</li>
    <li>Time: {{ trip_item.time }}</li>
    <li>Location: {{ trip_item.location }}</li>
    <li>Item Type: {{ trip_item.item_type }}</li>
    <li>Item Number: {{ trip_item.item_number }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Is there anything wrong with `views.py` and `activity.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to put `<ul>` tag inside the for loop:

```
{% for trip_item in trip.activity_set.all %}
<ul>
    <li>Activity name: {{ trip_item.activity_name }}</li>
    <li>Date: {{ trip_item.date }}</li>
    <li>Time: {{ trip_item.time }}</li>
    <li>Location: {{ trip_item.location }}</li>
    <li>Item Type: {{ trip_item.item_type }}</li>
    <li>Item Number: {{ trip_item.item_number }}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```